# Include a maven project with gradle in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, gradle

I want to use the minimal-json project (http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.eclipsesource.minimal-json) and get this with gradle. So I create a gradle.build file in my Workspace with:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'maven'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    compile group: 'com.eclipsesource.minimal-json:minimal-json:0.9.3', name: 'minimal-json', version: '0.9.3'
    testCompile group: 'com.eclipsesource.minimal-json:minimal-json:0.9.3', name: 'minimal-json', version: '0.9.3'
}
```

After this I do **gradle eclipse**. This works without an error.

```
[sts] -----------------------------------------------------
[sts] Starting Gradle build for the following tasks: 
[sts]      eclipse
[sts] -----------------------------------------------------
:eclipseClasspath
:eclipseJdt
:eclipseProject
:eclipse

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 6.401 secs
[sts] -----------------------------------------------------
[sts] Build finished succesfully!
[sts] Time taken: 0 min, 7 sec
[sts] -----------------------------------------------------
```

After this I want to import this builded project with **File** -> **Import...** -> **Gradle Project** -> **Build Model** I can't find any project. What I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:-
Try importing the project as a normal java project, than as a gradle project into the workspace.

IMPORT-> GENERAL -> EXISTING PROJECT INTO WORKSPACE.